# Minimizing the median of squared differences

Tags: median, estimators

I have a sorted set of real numbers $x_{1}...x_{n}$ and would like to find $y$ to minimize the median of $(x_{i}-y)^{2}$.

Is there an algorithm and a correctness proof for it?

I understand I need to look at segments of the type $[x_{i},x_{i+n/2}]$ and check for the shortest one. But how can I prove that?

Comment: Calling $y$ a "mean" may confuse many readers, because "mean" has a standard definition. It appears you are seeking a kind of *average* $y$, depending on the $(x_i)$, that minimizes the median of the $(x_i-y)^2$. (Note that $y$ is unlikely to be unique.) Moreover, you do not seem to be *estimating* anything about a population or process that the data may represent: you want to *compute* $y$. Are these interpretations correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree with your corrections. The problem does relate strongly to estimation.

Comment: Side note: You can replace the square within the median by any monotone increasing function $g$ of $|x_i-y|$ without changing your optimal solution.